# Does solr have post-commit hooks (or something else) to notify slaves?

Tags: solr

I want the Solr master server to call the slaves' replication handler when it commits. I want to pass a `commitWithin` and a URL to call **when** the commit actually happens.

I want it (post-commit hook URLs) to **notify the slaves** as soon as master commits so that slaves can start pulling.

Currently we commit on master, then call `solr/CORE/replication/?...` for each slave. Now I want to change to commitWithin.

Comment: Without knowing too much but it seems that you've chosen to not use the default "thinking" when it comes to Solr. Solr slaves should decide themselves when to pull in new data and not "get forcefed" data, so to speak. If you need to have "realtime" replication then lowering the `pollInterval` time would be the way to go. That being said, the next question would be why do you want the master to control replication?

Comment: We currently commit on master and wait for the response, then call slave replication handler; we do all this programatically. Change commit to commitWithin in this workflow, and you need something else right?

Comment: I would skip the calling of the replication handler all together and save some headaches. Solr slaves have the ability to pull data by themselves and they will get issued a "wait" if a commit is ongoing on the master.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Solr (at least the latest one) has a [flexible post-commit hook](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#A.22Update.22_Related_Event_Listeners). And it is triggered by Solr itself, so will know when the commit actually happened (to answer the comment about commitWithin).